# Need to insert a reference (right-centered) after a caption

Tags: floats, captions

I have a small problem. Please have a look at the Screenshot.[image]

What I need to do is to put one more empty line BEFORE (Khan et al., 2011, 30). When I try to do this, it always moves the citation back to the left side. I tried to insert `\\` and `\linebreak` and also `\newline` but when I do so, it always moves the citation back to the left side. I need it on the right side still, just one line down. This is the code that I use currently:

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{center}
   \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth]{Fallstudie3_Resultate_2.png} % auch mit absoluter Groessenangabe: width=5cm bzw. height=5cm
\end{center}
\caption{Resultat aus dem zweiten Experiment}\label{Fig:example}
\hfill
\citep[30]{Khan14}
\end{figure}
```

When I remove the \hfill, then the citation is switching to the left side. So that is why I inserted  `\hfill` there. I thought that I could simply add `\\` before `\citep[30]{Khan14}` but that does not work.

Some help would be highly appreciated. regards

Answer (score 1):

Leave an empty line, then simply add another `\hfill` like:

```
% previous code
\hfill

\hfill \citep[30]{Khan14}
```

It will add an extra empty line.

Comment: that worked. Thanks a lot! Sometimes the answer is so easy but you just don't see it :=)